# ajax implement on internal pages jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

im making an internal page jquery mobile ive search question here in stackover but those are not similar to mine.i want to know if it is possible to use ajax in loading internal pages.i want to load my about1 page and about2 page in the about page here is my sample code:

```
<!-- start about -->
    <div data-role="page" id="about" data-url="about" data-theme="a">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup" >
                 <h3 class="ui-title"  >
                            Header
                        </h3>
                <!-- working back button <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">go back</a> -->
                 <a data-role="button"  data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                            Back
                            </span></span></a>
                 <a data-role="button" href="#home" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                            Home
                            </span></span></a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="header" data-icon="bars" data-theme="d" class="ui-header ui-bar-b" >
                 <h1 class="ui-title"  >About</h1>

            </div>
            <!-- start ajax -->
                <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" id="mylist" class="ui-listview">
                    <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-screen-hidden">
                        <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                        <div class="ui-btn-text">
                        <a href="#about" class="ui-link-inherit" data-transition="fade">about</a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-a">
                        <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                        <div class="ui-btn-text">
                        <a href="#about1" class="ui-link-inherit" data-transition="pop">about</a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>                
                        <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-last ui-btn-up-a">
                        <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                        <div class="ui-btn-text">
                        <a href="#about2" class="ui-link-inherit" data-transition="turn">about2</a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <!-- end ajax -->
             <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup" >
                 <h3 class="ui-title"  >Footer</h3>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end about -->
    <!-- start about1 -->
    <div data-role="page" id="about1" data-url="about1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup" >
                 <h3 class="ui-title"  >
                            Header
                        </h3>
                <!-- working back button <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">go back</a> -->
                 <a data-role="button"  data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                            Back
                            </span></span></a>
                 <a data-role="button" href="#home" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                            Home
                            </span></span></a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="header" data-icon="bars" data-theme="d" class="ui-header ui-bar-b" >
                 <h1 class="ui-title"  >About1</h1>

            </div>
             <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup" >
                 <h3 class="ui-title"  >Footer</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- end about1 -->
        <!-- start about2 -->
    <div data-role="page" id="about2" data-url="about2">
                <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup" >
                 <h3 class="ui-title"  >
                            Header
                        </h3>
                <!-- working back button <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">go back</a> -->
                 <a data-role="button"  data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                            Back
                            </span></span></a>
                 <a data-role="button" href="#home" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                            Home
                            </span></span></a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="header" data-icon="bars" data-theme="d" class="ui-header ui-bar-b" >
                 <h1 class="ui-title"  >About2</h1>
            </div>
             <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup" >
                 <h3 class="ui-title"  >Footer</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- end about2-->
```

Comment: Yes, you can load jquery mobile pages via `AJAX`, did you tried it??

Comment: yeah i tried but i failed can you tell me how?

Comment: Means you are getting html, but not as jquery mobile page, rt?

Comment: i wanted to do jquery mobile but im just new in using jquery mobile i dont know how to.i tried it like on how to implement ajax using external page but its not working :)

Comment: By using `AJAX`, are you getting html content??

Comment: yes..you can see my sample on top i have a main page its called about page and i want to load about1 and about2 pages inside about page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38524/discussion-between-ajith-s-and-satine-kianne)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do jquery mobile page load as `AJAX`,

Your `AJAX` should be,

```
$( "#your_success_ele_id1" ).load( "about1.html", function() {
     $('#your_success_ele_id1').trigger('create');
});
$( "#your_success_ele_id2" ).load( "about2.html", function() {
     $('#your_success_ele_id2').trigger('create');
});
```

`trigger('create')` should be used, otherwise you will get an normal html page

This you can use for onclick of an element.

Comment: is this ajax used for internal coz i dont know what to put in he url coz im just using like a #tag so i load a page..

Comment: ok i still dont know the part on which div i should load them..and i dont get this one $( "#your_success_ele_id1" ) and this $( "#your_success_ele_id2" )

Comment: `your_success_ele_id1` and `your_success_ele_id2` is the `div`s `id` in which your `html` page to loaded